# How can I List only hard drives in JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

Is there a way of listing only the root drives in the JFileChooser?I mean I need to prevent listing the optical media drive/removable drive in JFilechooser..I am using java6.

thanx in advance

### UPDATE

Or knowing that the file choosed is from a CD/DVD drive will do...Is is possible in a platform independent manner?

thanx

Comment: Look at setting a custom [`FileSystemView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html).

Comment: if your problem is solved by my answer  then you can select my answer

Answer (score 1):

> By default, a file chooser displays all of the files and directories
>   that it detects, except for hidden files. A program can apply one or
>   more file filters to a file chooser so that the chooser shows only
>   some files. The file chooser calls the filter's accept method for each
>   file to determine whether it should be displayed. A file filter
>   accepts or rejects a file based on criteria such as file type, size,
>   ownership, and so on. Filters affect the list of files displayed by
>   the file chooser. The user can enter the name of any file even if it
>   is not displayed.

here the link [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters)